# I can't use Visual Studio Designer, invalid markup?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I use Visual Studio 2017. The IDE tells me

```
The type or namespace name 'SalamanderWindow' does not exist in the namespace 'SalamanderWnmp.UserClass'
```

**SalamanderWindow.cs**

```
public class SalamanderWindow : Window
{
    public SalamanderWindow()
    {
        this.Style = Application.Current.Resources["BaseWindow"] as Style;
        this.SourceInitialized += delegate (object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this._HwndSource = PresentationSource.FromVisual((Visual)sender) as HwndSource;
        };
    }
    //...
}
```

[image]

Comment: Why is it `local:SalamanderWindow` instead of just `Window` with `x:Class="YourNamespace.SalamanderWindow"`?

Comment: I add some functions in SalamanderWindow, all of my windows extend it.

Comment: As long as it's just an intermediate class in CodeBehind without any extended XAML, this doesn't really matter. Just use `Window` in XAML and the most derived class as `x:Class`

Comment: I have to use SalamanderWindow, because my AboutWindow extends it
     public partial class AboutWin : SalamanderWindow

Comment: Then try whether just using SalamanderWindow all the way solves your problem: `<local:SalamanderWindow.Resources>` instead of `<Window.Resources>` and so on.

Comment: I still can not use the designer, though my code can run without errors. I am puzzled by it for a long time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159593/discussion-between-salamander-and-grek40).